# Программа завершается при импорте tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

Скрипт просто завершает свою работу, как если бы была выполнена функция `exit()`.

Код:

```py
print('Before')
import tensorflow
print('After')
```

Вывод:

```
Before
```

Исключений, наряду с предупреждениями, в консоли нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наконец я нашёл решение (вероятно, не самое лучшее, но я уже отчаялся) - downgrade до `tensorflow-2.12.0`:

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
pip install tensorflow==2.12.0
```